# Can i use percentage in height in div with overflow-y: scroll in it?

Tags: html, css

Can i use percentage in height in div with overflow-y: scroll in it?
the markup:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="messages_container">
<ol class="messages">
<li>sample message here</li>
<li>sample message here</li>
<li>sample message here</li>
</ol>
</div>
<div class="reply">
<form>
<fieldset>
<textarea cols="60" rows="1" name="message"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using percentage, use viewport height (vh) which is explained in this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141991/why-does-the-overflow-y-property-not-work-with-percent-height) and I also did a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/headwinds/q5j9x0k4/) to see for myself

So instead of:

```
display: block;
width: 100%    
height: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Use:

```
display: block;
width: 100vh;    
height: 50vh;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: Holy smokes. This actually works.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot.

Try doing that with JS, should be easier than to hack around with CSS.