# Why Does The overflow-y Property Not Work With Percent Height

Tags: css, height, overflow

I'm trying to use percentage height with `overflow-y:auto;`  and instead of creating a scroll bar on the side of the div, it's using the page scroll bar.

Here's an example of want I'm getting at: http://jsfiddle.net/hmwe2jty/

Is it possible to use this property with percent height?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use the viewport height/width instead of a percentage. Change 100% to 100vh, and you're done!

## EDIT:

The percentages take the precentage of the parent element. For example:

```js
console.log("Parent's width: " + document.getElementById("parent").offsetWidth);
console.log("Child's width: " + document.getElementById("child").offsetWidth);
```

```css
#parent {
  background: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
}

#child {
  background: orange;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    I am 250px wide!
  </div>
</div>
```

The new CSS3 viewport units use the user's viewport as a base. For example:

```js
console.log("Parent's width: " + document.getElementById("parent").offsetWidth);
console.log("Child's width: " + document.getElementById("child").offsetWidth);
```

```css
#parent {
  background: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
}

#child {
  background: orange;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    My width is 50% of the user's viewport, regardless of the size of my parent!
  </div>
</div>
```

Because the body element is a bit weird, it's default behaviour is to shrink to fit is contents. So:

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
The body element wraps around it contents, <br>
but the backgound just ignores this behaviour.
```

So, since the parent element is the body, you will need to use the new vw and vh units. Read a article on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

### EDIT 2:

Another way to choose the viewport as parent would be to make the element's position either `fixed` or `absolute`. In that instance the parent would become the viewport, thus giving you the needed value.

Comment: I think vh is not supported by some version of safari. I am facing the issue in ipad while using vh.

Answer (score 1):

use this css for div which height must dimensioned in percents of parent element:

```css
  .child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 0px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is considering 100% of the parent, which is the body. Hence it occupies the height of complete space available. Specify height a lesser amount in % rather than 100 (if you specifically prefer percent). It is upto you what you chose.